# Need Help for : The source must not be null in flutter

Tags: flutter, exception, arguments

i have mobile app with flutter ,after login page it is redirect to home page ,as below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
    
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}    
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      var m_id;
      var u_id;
      // get logined user profile
      var logined_user;
      var logined_email;
      getuser() async {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        logined_user = preferences.getString('username');
        logined_email = preferences.getString('email');
    
        if (logined_user != null) {
          setState(() {
            logined_user = preferences.getString('username');
            logined_email = preferences.getString('email');
          });
        }
        var data = {'username': logined_user};
        var url = "http://10.0.2.2/jiyan/test/api/users/status_user.php";
        var response = await http.post(
          url,
          body: data,
        );
        var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        if (responsebody['status'] == 'success') {
          setState(() {
            m_id = responsebody['m_id'];
          });
        } else {
          print(responsebody['status']);
        }
      }
      @override
      void initState() {
        getuser();
        super.initState();
      }   
      //App Start
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              title: Text(
                'ژیان و قورئان',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                children: <Widget>[
                  //course 1
                  InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('week');
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/images/months/Months1.png'))),
                  //course 2
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '2'),
                  //course 3
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '3'),
                  //course 4
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '4'),
                  //course 5
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '5'),
                  //course 6
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '6'),
                  //course 7
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '7'),
                  //course 8
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '8'),
                  //course 9
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '9'),
                  //course 10
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '10'),
                  //course 11
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '11'),
                  //course 12
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '12'),
                  //course 13
                  buildInkWellCourses(context, '13'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
}
InkWell buildInkWellCourses(BuildContext context, coursenum) {
        return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              if (int.parse(m_id) > int.parse(coursenum) - 1) {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('week');
              }
            },
            child: int.parse(m_id) >= int.parse(coursenum)
                ? Image(
                    image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/images/months/Months' + coursenum + '.png'))
                : Image(
                    image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/images/months/Months' + coursenum + 'closed.png')));
      }
}
```

when i run the app on emulator i get this error :

Invalid argument(s): The source must not be null
The relevant error-causing widget was
Home
#0      int.parse  (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:53:25)
#1      _HomeState.buildInkWellCourses
package:jiyanUquraan/pages/home.dart:122
#2      _HomeState.build
package:jiyanUquraan/pages/home.dart:84
#3      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4619
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild

How can i fixed this error

Comment: It seems *m_id* is null in your *buildInkWellCourses* function.

Comment: @Snurrig no sir i printed it ,it is have value

Comment: hey so can you just show a sample m_id

Comment: @KrishBhanushali how can i show it? all buildInkWellCourses depends on m_id and they worked correctly ,but i think i have problem with login page

Answer (score 0):

See You had a problem when you logged in if the login_id was null it even after

```
if (logined_user != null) {
          setState(() {
            logined_user = preferences.getString('username');
            logined_email = preferences.getString('email');
          });
        }
```

This function may also give you logined_user as null and then you would go and call the server and it would result error
So I have made changes and it should work if you handle the error where I have specified
please surely handle the error asnot handling it may create a red screen on your app
Below is the rectified code

```
getuser() async {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        logined_user = preferences.getString('username');
        logined_email = preferences.getString('email');
        

        //Here it may be causing problem so I just debugged your code

        if (logined_user == null || logined_email == null) {
          setState(() {
            //Just handle your error
          });
        }
        else{
          var data = {'username': logined_user};
        var url = "http://10.0.2.2/jiyan/test/api/users/status_user.php";
        var response = await http.post(
          url,
          body: data,
        );
        var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        if (responsebody['status'] == 'success') {
          setState(() {
            m_id = responsebody['m_id'];
          });
        } else {
          print(responsebody['status']);
        }
        }
        
        
      }
```

Comment: thanks alot
but i get the username and email correctly
i think the problem is in the first page ,I will put the login page code and update the question

Comment: this is login page code: https://pastebin.com/UBZkHiTQ

Comment: i tested it ,it is from the if statement that check if there is username saved then Navigate to home page

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it ,just I changed :

```
var m_id;
```

to

```
var m_id='0';
```